# how to know origin about strange conections in springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using springboot for a project, and there was a module in that I had to make a **scraping** to get some data of a website to collect some statical data that I save after in postgress... But in my daily log of wildfly I have seen strange connections to unknown websites like baidu.com, cn.bing.com:443, and [www.voanews.com:443](http://www.voanews.com:443)

I relate my **scraping** connection with this, but I don't know what is the origin of that connection attempts... how can I know?

I am using gargoylesoftware to make the **scraping**, and my wildfly is over http, no https...

```java
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpMethod;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebRequest;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomNodeList;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
```

These are the error logs that I have in my wildfly...

```
2019-06-07 02:07:50,557 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default I/O-1) UT005071: Undertow request failed HttpServerExchange{ CONNECT www.voanews.com:443 request {Proxy-Connection=[Keep-Alive], Proxy-Authorization=[Basic Og==], User-Agent=[PycURL/7.43.0 libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3], Host=[www.voanews.com:443]} response {}}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000068: Servlet path match failed
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletPathMatchesData.getServletHandlerByPath(ServletPathMatchesData.java:83)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletPathMatches.getServletHandlerByPath(ServletPathMatches.java:88)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:151)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.HttpContinueReadHandler.handleRequest(HttpContinueReadHandler.java:65)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PathHandler.handleRequest(PathHandler.java:94)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.Host$OptionsHandler.handleRequest(Host.java:386)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.HttpContinueReadHandler.handleRequest(HttpContinueReadHandler.java:65)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.Host$AcmeResourceHandler.handleRequest(Host.java:405)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.Host$HostRootHandler.handleRequest(Host.java:414)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.NameVirtualHostHandler.handleRequest(NameVirtualHostHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.error.SimpleErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SimpleErrorPageHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.CanonicalPathHandler.handleRequest(CanonicalPathHandler.java:49)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.Server$DefaultHostHandler.handleRequest(Server.java:189)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.ChannelUpgradeHandler.handleRequest(ChannelUpgradeHandler.java:211)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http2.Http2UpgradeHandler.handleRequest(Http2UpgradeHandler.java:102)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisallowedMethodsHandler.handleRequest(DisallowedMethodsHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:360)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEventWithNoRunningRequest(HttpReadListener.java:255)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:136)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpOpenListener.handleEvent(HttpOpenListener.java:147)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpOpenListener.handleEvent(HttpOpenListener.java:93)
    at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpOpenListener.handleEvent(HttpOpenListener.java:52)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners$10.handleEvent(ChannelListeners.java:291)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners$10.handleEvent(ChannelListeners.java:286)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92)
    at org.xnio.nio.QueuedNioTcpServer$1.run(QueuedNioTcpServer.java:131)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.safeRun(WorkerThread.java:612)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:479)
```

Comment: You can enable `access logs` to have more information about incoming requests.

Comment: FYI it's __scraping__ (and __scrape__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrapping, 'Scrapping' means throwing things away like rubbish.